# Java class object hashing changes without source changes

Tags: java, class, object, hash, version

What I'm trying to do:
I want to ensure that after any change is made to a source file, a developer increments a developer set static value.  If the developer fails to increment the version, an error is thrown.

What I'm doing:
I have a test program that obtains an input stream from the class object, and runs it through an MD5 hashing algorithm. At which point I record the hash and version number, forming a data-pair. If the hash changes without the version changing an error is thrown.

My problem is:
For the most part the code is working as intended, identifying when a class has changed but the developer version has not. However I'm encountering intermittent changes in the output hash despite no apparent changes to the actual source code.

My method for my testing is:

- Test 01: compile code, run test program, and record hash.
- Test 02: delete class files, compile code, run test program, and record hash.
- Test 03: delete class files, change code, compile, run test program, and record hash.  (the hash changes at this point)
- Test 04: delete class files, reverse the change in the previous build, compile, run test program, and record hash.

After Test04, the hash *should* be the same as the hash from Test02 since the change has been reverted, however this is not the case.

My question is:
Is there a variable I'm not seeing or accounting for?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Couldn't serialVersionUID be used? http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4/pdf/serial-spec.pdf http://www.mkyong.com/java-best-practices/understand-the-serialversionuid/

Comment: Do you want to detect changes to the code, or just the public interface of the class?

Comment: I suspect those changes are timestamp/datetime problems somewhere embedded in the class files. The reproduceability you are trying to achieve is also influenced by the compiler and its switches you are using. Have you looked at code signing? Maybe it could help you with your requirements. It also may be better to hash/track the source files to find changes.

Comment: Why don't you just manage this via source control? Your approach does not make any sense to me, it's just painful for each and every developer.

Comment: Pretty irritating, use a commit hook.

Comment: When you have a changed hash that you think shouldn't have happened, what does a regular file comparison program say about the two files?

Answer (score 1):

Why not let Java compute a `serializationId` for you? Many changes should automatically cause the computed one to change.

That said, why are you doing this? If you use continuous integration and Maven/Ivy that might achieve what you are trying to do.

Comment: Indeed, this is the best solution.